# How record line in audio on iPhone with lightning jack?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, video, microphone

I've been tearing my hair out over this one: when recording audio or video with my iPhone, I can't figure out how to use the Lightning port for an audio-in signal.

I do not have an analog headphone jack on my phone so Lightning/USB are the only ways I know/prefer to get the recording done. _(n.b. Another question could cover iPhone 6s / 2016 iPhone SE which were the last phones to have analog in via mini jack / headphones without needing an adapter)

For example, I'm filming someone playing an instrument, and I want to use the audio-out of that instrument as the direct sound source for the video. (without holding a microphone near the speakers)

I have tried a 3.5mm 4-pin minijack cable from the instrument to the iPhone (with the [Apple minijack-to-Lightning converter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMX62AM/A/lightning-to-35-mm-headphone-jack-adapter)) but this 4-pin audio cable is not recognised as a microphone/sound input. I have also read an article about soldering your own cable with the right resistor values, but that can't be the only way to record audio on an iPhone.

The only microphone that gets recognised is the one that is built into the official Apple EarPods.

How can I record an audio source directly into my iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a Lightning audio interface. There's a lot of different products in various price ranges from a number of makers. Note that there are some that are targetted at specific instruments such as guitar or bass, or microphones - and some have multiple types of inputs.

You could for example take a look at the [Line 6 Sonic Port](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CS4L7DK) audio interface for Lightning or similar.

If you want something for 3.5mm minijack, you could instead look at the [Tascam iXZ Microphone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005NZ05J8) and Audio Interface for iOS (approx. 60$).

Any assorted music store, or online vendors such as Amazon, has multiple types of these products. Some cheaper than the these, some much more expensive.

Comment: I've used the Tascam device, (I don't own it,) and it works as advertized..

Comment: Thanks! That was the missing link! Apparently you can even use regular audio interfaces with an iphone! https://youtu.be/Sc-_LiuqiRA

Comment: Yes, if you have an existing USB audio interface, they usually work OK with iOS devices - however note that you almost always have to have a powered USB hub to connect it through. Even that has sometimes given me problems with the iOS device giving warnings about not enough power.

Comment: I’m inclined to try that, since I already have a regular audio interface connected to my macbook. Still it’s a whole lot of wiring for something that should be simple....

Comment: Well, why would it be "simple" ? .... the cable you have used probably just has the signal wired on the wrong parts of the jack plug - if you just correct the cable you can get a signal in "simple"... but if you want high audio quality, the "simple" solution is never going to be great.

Comment: I'd be happy with a link to that cable though :) Even it it's not great quality.

Comment: Well, you haven't told us anything about what kind of instrument you have... so I cannot really guess what kind of plug you want on that cable. The 3.5 mm minijack for the iPhone/Android is split into 4 parts starting from the tip of the plug: left out, right out, ground, microphone. If you've use a 3 part plug you wouldn't get any mic in ofcourse.

Comment: The simple question remains: device X has line-out .This could be a synthesizer, a record player, anything really. Is there no way to record the line-out directly on an iPhone without using an audio interface? Some people mention soldering cables but I've never seen any product that can do this. I'm just wondering why this has to be so complex. My old windows 98 pc with a 10 dollar sound card had an audio-in that could record any line-out from any source. Why can't phones do this?

Comment: Your question seems to be based on a misunderstanding. Which iPhone model in particular do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a [DI box](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000B85FV0) can also get your Line Level to Mic Level signal for the iphone to recognize the signal in its mic port. I've not tested this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Could you edit this to include specifically how the XLR output of that device interfaces to an iPhone? I’m going to edit the question as well since it’s not clear how the iPhone will receive audio.